# I am getting an error , when using a custom made function in `tapply()` or `by()` operator

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am getting an error , when using a custom made function in `tapply()` or `by()` operator.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(m=c(rep("a",4),rep("b",3),rep("c",2)),
                  n1 =round(rnorm(mean = 20,sd = 10,n = 9)))
#> dat
 m n1
1 a 14
2 a 22
3 a 12
4 a 36
5 b 23
6 b 12
7 b 25
8 c 27
9 c 26
# the custom function
fcor <- function(x,y){
  return(cor(x,y))
}

z <- 1:9 # separate vector

tapply(dat$n1,dat$m,mean) # no error.

by(dat$n1,dat$m,fcor(y=z)) # error
tapply(dat$n1,dat$m,fcor(y=z)) #error
```

Also ,Is there any difference in between `tapply()` or `by()` , that I should know about, other than their output format.

Comment: `fcor(y, z)` in your `tapply` and `by` calls, not `fcor(y=z)`.  If that doesn't work, knowing the error message would be helpful.

Comment: @Limey didnot work , error ` Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default ` .

Comment: You need to call an anonymous function,  try `by/tapply(dat$n1,dat$m, function(x) fcor(x, y=z))`. However length `z` should correspond to that of `x` so you'll get another error.

Comment: @jay.sf producing error : ` Error in cor(x, y) : incompatible dimensions `

Comment: @DRPR Yeah, I tried to explain that in may previous comment ;)

Comment: What @jay.sf says.  Read the online doc.  Have another go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

- the third argument to `by` must be a function but `fcor(y = z)` is not a function.  It is an attempt to evaluate a function.
- both `n1` and `z` need to be subsetted.  One cannot take the correlation of a subset of `n1` with `z` as they have a different lengths.
- `fcor` seems pointless since it performs the same operation as `cor`.

Either of these would work:

```
by(cbind(dat, z), dat$m, function(x) with(x, cor(n1, z)))

by(cbind(dat, z), dat$m, with, cor(n1, z))
```

To use `tapply` operate on the row index:

```
tapply(1:nrow(dat), dat$m, function(ix) cor(dat$n1[ix], z[ix]))
```